# SVG from Figma displays grid lines in Chrome but not in Edge, how to resolve?

Tags: html, css, svg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRsNs.png)**Description:**

I'm encountering an issue with an SVG file that I exported from Figma and integrated into my HTML project using Tailwind CSS. For the first two days, everything worked perfectly. However, now the SVG is displaying grid lines in Google Chrome, while it continues to work correctly in Microsoft Edge.

**Problem:**

- The SVG displays grid lines only in Google Chrome when viewed within my HTML project, but not in Edge.
- When I open the same SVG directly in Chrome or Edge, it displays correctly without any grid lines.

**Steps Taken:**

1. I've checked my project's HTML and CSS to ensure that there are no unintentional styles affecting the SVG.
2. I confirmed that there are no conflicting CSS rules that target the SVG element.
3. I verified that the original SVG file (exported from Figma) does not contain grid lines.
4. I updated Chrome to the latest version and cleared the browser cache, but the issue persists.

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTiKj.png)**Expected Outcome:**

   I expect the SVG to render consistently without grid lines in both Chrome and Edge, just as it did during the initial two days of development.

```
<svg width="2120" height="1877" viewBox="0 0 2120 1877" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g filter="url(#filter0_f_300_160)">
<rect x="1026.57" y="608.013" width="487.075" height="466.254" fill="#2D81E5"/>
<path d="M1348.15 861.842L1412.33 1050.92H1620.01L1451.99 1167.77L1516.17 1356.85L1348.15 1239.99L1180.13 1356.85L1244.31 1167.77L1076.29 1050.92H1283.97L1348.15 861.842Z" fill="#EFE059"/>
<ellipse cx="734.134" cy="1019.36" rx="234.134" ry="224.126" fill="#59ABE6"/>
<ellipse cx="1008.7" cy="724.126" rx="234.134" ry="224.126" fill="#59E6B3"/>
<ellipse cx="1026.57" cy="1135.47" rx="252" ry="241.228" fill="#C859EF"/>
</g>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_f_300_160" x="0" y="0" width="2120.01" height="1876.7" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="250" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_300_160"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```